# VBA How to return absolute cell reference value to attach to a hyperlink reference

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to record a macro to apply hyperlinks to the numbers and "OK"s by referencing to top row value and most left column value which represents a named range.

It is always applied to the same sheet. There is no criteria for adding the links.

My editted macro is as below, am I doing anything wrong?
[image]

```
Sub Hyperlink()
    '
    ' Hyperlink Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
    '
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'2RowFinCalc'!_" & Range(RC26).Value() & Range(R5C).Value()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your post does not have enough information for us to help you.  Are the hyperlinks always to the same sheet?  If there a criteria for adding the links and the "OK"s?  Please review site guidelines on [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Comment: Also, was this actually recorded, `Range(RC26).Value() & Range(R5C).Value()` , or did you add that to the recorded macro?

Comment: Yes. It is always applied to the same sheet.
There is no criteria for adding the links. 
Yes the `Range(RC26).Value() & Range(R5C).Value()` was editted as I was trying to use absolute reference in the VBA code.

Comment: Note that in `Range(RC26)` the  `RC26` is considered as a variable name not as a value! I recommend to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* so you don't run into such issues.

Comment: Will you apply the hyperlinks to the range 'AE7:AL14'? if so, when clicking the OK in e.g. cell 'AI7',  what cell or range will it 'jump' to? (guessing 'AI12') Where will e.g cells 'AF10' or 'AH11' point to? When I click on the OK in 'AL10', where will it 'jump' to?

Comment: I would name AE7:AL14 as a named range. Then apply those hyperlinks to those named ranged. That way would be faster. I won't be applying hyperlinks to those cells in AL column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Cells` property of `Range` object whcih lets you use row and column indexes of wanted range:

```
Sub Hyperlink()
    '
    ' Hyperlink Macro
    '
    ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
    '
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
        "'2RowFinCalc'!_" & Cells(Selection.Row, 26).Value & Cells(5, Selection.Column).Value
End Sub
```